# Write Hermite equation in specific form. Hence show $u=p^\frac{1}{2}y$ satisfies equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Write the Hermite equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}-2x\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+2\alpha y=0$$

> in the form

$$\frac{\partial (p(x)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial y)}{\partial x}+q(x)y=0$$

> Hence show that the function $u=p^\frac{1}{2}y$ satisfies

$$u''+(2\alpha+1-x^2)u=0$$

> I have

$$y''+py'+q(x)y=0$$$$ry''+rpy'+rq(x)y=0$$$$ry''+pry'=(ry')'=ry''+r'y'$$$$r'=pr, r=e^{\int p(x)dx}$$

> But where to from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(p(x)\frac{dy}{dx} \right)+q(x)y=0$$
$$py''+p'y'+qy=0$$
$$y''+\frac{p'}{p}y'+\frac{q}{p}=0$$
to be compared to $$\quad y''-2xy'+2\alpha y=0 \quad\implies$$
$$\begin{cases}\frac{p'}{p}=-2x \quad\to\quad p(x)= c\: e^{-x^2}\\
 \frac{q}{p}=2\alpha \quad\to\quad q(x)=2\alpha p=2\alpha c\: e^{-x^2}
\end{cases}$$
$$u(x)=p^{1/2}y=c^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2}y$$
$u'=c^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2}\left(y'-xy \right)$

$u''=c^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2}\left(y''-xy'-y-x(y'-xy) \right)=c^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2}\left(y''-2xy'+x^2y \right)$
$$u''+(2\alpha+1-x^2)u=c^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2}\left((y''-2xy'-y+x^2y)+(2\alpha+1-x^2)y \right)$$ 
After simplification :
$$u''+(2\alpha+1-x^2)u=c^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2}\left(y''-2xy'+2\alpha y \right)$$
Since $\quad y''-2xy'+2\alpha y=0 \quad\implies$
$$u''+(2\alpha+1-x^2)u=0$$